# Consulta MYSQL: ¿Cómo obtener por pares nombres que terminan misma letra sin repeticiones?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy utilizando la versión MySQL 8.0, y a continuación ingreso imagen con el `show create table pueblos`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT p1.nombre, p2.nombre 
    FROM pueblos p1 JOIN pueblos p2 ON
    mid(p1.nombre, char_length(p1.nombre), 1) = mid(p2.nombre, 
    char_length(p2.nombre), 1)
    WHERE p1.nombre <> p2.nombre;
```

Al realizar esta consulta, estoy haciendo un `JOIN` sobre una misma tabla y con ello logro agrupar dos nombres que terminan con la misma letra, sin embargo, como verán en la siguiente imagen los nombres se repiten pero ahora en la columna contraria (como se ve en la imagen de abajo). ¿Cómo puedo evitar ese comportamiento?

Fíjense en las filas 1 y 7 o en la 2 y 5. Estas repeticiones son las que quiero evitar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si pudieras explicar un poco mas

Comment: Deberías hacer un group by, para agrupar los nombres iguales.

Comment: Tengo soluciones pero necesito saber la versión de mySQL con la que trabajas y/o la estructura de la tabla `pueblos`, para ver qué es lo que resulta más sencillo y no escribir una respuesta kilométrica y complicada.

Comment: Realicé una edición donde agrego la versión de mysql y `show create table pueblos` . Disculpen por favor la falta de información.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto es similar a un bucle que va de `i = 0` hasta el final de lista, con un bucle anidado que va de `j = i + 1` hasta el final de lista. La intención de estos bucles es comparar `i` contra todo lo que le sigue y nunca hacia atrás, de esta forma no se repiten los pares `(i, j)`.

Una forma de implementar esto en MySQL es usando el `ID` de las filas en tu tabla, que yo estoy considerando como `pueblo_id`.

```sql
SELECT
  DISTINCT p1.nombre, p2.nombre 
FROM pueblos p1 JOIN pueblos p2 ON
    mid(p1.nombre, char_length(p1.nombre), 1) = mid(p2.nombre, 
    char_length(p2.nombre), 1)
WHERE
  p1.nombre <> p2.nombre AND
  p1.pueblo_id > p2.pueblo_id;
```

Lo cual da como resultados:

```
Burriana    Enramona
Benicarlo   Sanmateo
Soneja  Enramona
Soneja  Burriana
```

Te dejo un link hacia el fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43184a/2/0